# python passing function variables to another function

Tags: python, function, parameter-passing

I am trying to pass a variable from one function into my main engine function in a separate file. I have looked up other answers and gone through some but I can't seem to wrap my head around it..

load_file.py

```
def get_connection():
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute(
        "SELECT ID, Type, Server, Port, User, Password, isActive, FileExtension, FileContains, FileLocation, "
    "ScheduleMinutes, IntervalTime from DataConnection WHERE isActive=True")

    data_connection = cursor.fetchall()


def download_files(data_connection):
    for data_connection_detail in data_connection:
        connection_type = data_connection_detail[1]

        if connection_type == 'IMAP':
             ez_email.read_email_imap(data_connection_detail)

        elif connection_type == 'POP3':
             ez_email.read_email_pop3(data_connection_detail)

        elif connection_type == 'FTP':
             ez_ftp.easy_ftp(data_connection_detail)
```

main.py

```
from load_file import download_files
from load_file import get_connection

def run_engine():
    while True:
        get_connection()
        download_files()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    run_engine()
```

When I pass 'data_connection' to 'download_files' function it says I have an unfilled parameter inside of my main.py engine.

I'm sorry if this has already been answered but I'm just having trouble understanding it.

Comment: `get_connection()` returns something, but when you call it inside `run_engine()` you aren't saving the returned value...

Comment: Also, `download_files()` is defined to accept an argument, but when you call it, you aren't passing any arguments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

load_file.py

```
def get_connection():
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        cursor.execute(
            "SELECT ID, Type, Server, Port, User, Password, isActive, FileExtension, FileContains, FileLocation, "
        "ScheduleMinutes, IntervalTime from DataConnection WHERE isActive=True")
    
        return cursor.fetchall()

def download_files(data_connection):

        for data_connection_detail in data_connection:
            # type email will be IMAP, POP3, or FTP
            connection_type = data_connection_detail[1]

            # create data_source object
            if connection_type == 'IMAP':
                ez_email.read_email_imap(data_connection_detail)

            elif connection_type == 'POP3':
                ez_email.read_email_pop3(data_connection_detail)

            elif connection_type == 'FTP':
                ez_ftp.easy_ftp(data_connection_detail)
```

main.py

```
from load_file import get_connection
from load_file import download_files

def run_engine():
    while True:
        data = get_connection()
        download_files(data)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    run_engine()
```

The solution in this case is to return the object from the first function and use it as a parameter in the second.

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
def download_files(data_connection):
```

implies a parameter to be passed.

I think you might want

def run_engine():
while True:
conn = get_connection()
download_files(conn)

The `get_connection` function looks strange to me, like it's not returning a connection but the results of `fetchall`.

Comment: I didn't realize that I was returning data_connection, that was a mistake I edited it. The result of fetchall is the data that I am selecting from mysql. I am assigning that fetchall to data_connection and want to use those values inside of download_files.

Answer (score 0):

Your `download_files()` function has a required parameter (data_connection).  When you call it in run_engine, you are not passing a parameter.

You will need to capture the returned variable from get_connection and pass it to download_files, like this:

```
data_con = get_connection()  # place the returned variable from get_connection into a variable called data_con
download_files(data_con)     # pass that data_con variable to the download_files function
```

But the returned value from get_connection is not actually a connection in your current code - you'll need to make sure you're returning/passing the right variable.

Comment: -I made a mistake when posting, I didn't mean to be returning data_connection. I also added the connection string of the data I'm getting from cursor.fetchall(). data_connection is the value of the data that I'm selecting with mysql and fetchall() I want to use that data within download_files. Hopefully this makes more sense